# Any way to avoid reallocation in std::map when I need to modify a key?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dictionary

I need to modify the key of an element inside a `std::map`.
Currently, I'm doing this by erasing the element and re-inserting it with a different key.
Unfortunately, this is slow -- it involves an extra heap deallocation and reallocation.

What's the best way -- if there is any way -- to avoid the automatic node reallocation and destruction when I need to modify an element's key?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Nope, while the title is similar, the contents of the question don't seem to be. I'm not trying to re-index *all* the elements, but only a single one.

Comment: If heap allocation has too much overhead for you, a custom allocator is the way to go.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yeah I was thinking of that too, I was just hoping for a better way that doesn't depend on me changing the allocator. :\ But if you don't know of a better way feel free to just post that as an answer.

Comment: It may be worth having a look at [boost flat associative containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Haha thanks but I'm already aware of those, they're most *definitely* not appropriate for my use case unfortunately! I really need all (or almost all) the guarantees provided by the trees -- the ordering, the iterator integrity, the logarithmic complexity, etc.

Comment: note the answer by Howard Hinnant in the linked duplicate: he [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#839) avoiding the reallocation by adding `splice()` functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to avoid the node being deallocated and reallocated.

About the best I can think of would be to specify an Allocator with a lookaside list so when a node is reallocated soon after being freed, you can provide the same node very quickly/easily.

If you're certain the key change won't affect the relative order of the keys, you *could* modify the key in place (e.g., by specifying it as a mutable member), but doing so would lead to undefined behavior--chances are pretty good you can get away with it, *but* it's still officially undefined behavior.

Comment: In the special case where I know the element's *order* won't change relative to the other elements, is there anything I could do? (I'm thinking along the lines of making the key `mutable`, but I'm not sure what obstacles might lay ahead there.)

Comment: +1 best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least lesson the constructing part, depending on the insides of you mapped class. Consider the following example:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(){};
    A(int a)
    : a_(a)
    {
        std::cout << "construct" << std::endl;
    }

    A& operator=(const A& b)
    {
       a_ = b.a_;
       std::cout << "=" << std::endl;
    }

    A(A&& o)
    : a_(o.a_)
    {
        std::cout << "moved" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int a_;
};
```

It has a move constructor. By using `map.emplace` you can skip the reconstruction of your classes members:

```
std::map<int, A> mapper;

mapper[1] = A(1);
mapper[2] = A(2);
mapper.emplace(3, std::move(mapper[2]));
mapper.erase(mapper.find(2));
```

This will print out the following:

```
construct
=
construct
=
moved
```

indicating that the first two are constructed but the second one is moved. You will still have to delete your element and be careful about the move semantics.

If your `int a_` was replaced with something massive, you would be reducing the deep copy time and the deletion time by moving the data and deleting nothing.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The key and value are cheap to copy (in fact, they can be plain integers); that's not the problem. The problem is keeping the *node* inside of the map or set intact instead of destroying it only to recreate it moments later.

Comment: @Mehrdad yeah but it was fun for me to investigate this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this changes your design a bit, but consider instead using a pointer (or better, a shared_ptr) as the key. That way you can update the underlying data without ever updating the key.

Comment: It's not a question of being "able" to in the sense of getting around the compiler, but it's a question of being "able" to in the sense that it violates the invariants of the data structure. This doesn't really fix any problem.

Comment: @Mehrdad i think thats a fair point. Perhaps reading your question a bit too literally at 2am.